# Kafkadirectstrream: error consuming multiple topics with different number of partifion

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to consume two topic (each with different number of partitions) from a kafka broker using spark streaming directkafkastream API.
I'm having an OffsetOutRangeException on the second topic.I thinnk that is due to the fact that one topic is consumed before of the other.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. It could be you were passing outdated offsets to `topic-2` . Do you mind to share code of kafka conf setup.

Comment: Also, are you consuming from specific offsets or through `auto.offset.reset` (`smallest` or `largest`)?

Comment: I'm using the same kafka parameters and outo.offset.reset = smallest for both topics